# Meaning of 転がるように

Tags: meaning

I came across the phrase 転がるように in part of a sentence 間合いから転がるように脱出する.

[Here](https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E8%BB%A2%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB) I came across a definition saying すごいスピードで前に進むさま and was wondering whether this was correct, and if it is, how does it mean that?

Comment: Hi could you provide with a bit more context ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

転がるように can be used figuratively. For example, 転がるように as in 彼は坂を転がるように駆け下りた or 建物から転がるように逃げ出した usually describes how desperate this person was. He may have stumbled a few times, but it does not necessarily mean he has actually rolled physically. Your link is based on this figurative usage (although I think 転がるように usually implies "desperately" or something similarly negative. 転がるように成長する makes little sense.)

However, your sentence says 間合い — is this a kind of a battle scene? Then dodging by rolling in a battle is not strange, so 転がるように probably just means what it literally means, "as if one was rolling", "(dodge) like rolling".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure in you case

if I try to translate you sentence,:

"escape by rolling from an appropriate distance"